# Flex httpservice error handling

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using httpservice and once its called nothing happens. I don't get a result or an error? I have added various listeners but unable to catch any errors. Am i missing something?

```
    private function GetUsersServers():void
    {
        var serviceObj:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        serviceObj.resultFormat = 'text';
        serviceObj.method = 'GET';
        serviceObj.useProxy = false;
        serviceObj.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, GetUsersServersResult);
        serviceObj.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        serviceObj.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
        serviceObj.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        serviceObj.url = '************************';

        var parameters:Object = new Object();
        parameters["Username"] = m_strUserSIP;

        LogAddItem( -1, "GetUsersServers Request - User = " + parameters.Username);
        serviceObj.send(parameters);
    }

    private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        LogAddItem( LOG_CATEGORY_MAIN_DEBUG, "securityErrorHandler: " + loader.data);
    }

    // check for security error - probably crossdomain issue
    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        LogAddItem( LOG_CATEGORY_MAIN_DEBUG, "securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    public function onLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        LogAddItem( LOG_CATEGORY_MAIN_DEBUG, "Fault: " + e.text);
    }

    private function GetUsersServersResult(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        LogAddItem( -1, "GetUsersServers Result Received..");
        var rawData:String = String(event.result);
        LogAddItem( -1, "GetUsersServersResult = " + rawData);
        InitContinue();
    }
```

Comment: I think you should listen for the [fault](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#event:fault) event; I don't see any of the error events your listening for in the [docs](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you declare your `HTTPService` inside your function `GetUsersServers()`. When that function finishes, the variable holding the `HTTPService` no longer exists and is eligible for garbage collection.

Instead, if you declare the `HTTPService` as a member variable, the variable will exist throughout the lifetime of that class that it's in. So try something like this:

```
private var serviceObj:HTTPService;

private function GetUsersServers():void
{
    serviceObj = new HTTPService();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have made this change but unfortunately i still dont get a result/error. Are my listeners correct and can i add any more?

Comment: As long as an instance has event listeners attached to it, it is not eligible for garbage collection. I'm afraid this is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: @RIAstar it depends on how you add the listeners. I thought about that too. In this case, a listener is added to the HTTPService and the event handling function is in "this" class. So the HTTPService maintains a reference to "this" class ... "This" class has no reference to the HTTPService other than inside the function.

Comment: @VinceLowe it looks like your event listeners are also wrong. Take a look at [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#eventSummary) which shows the events that are dispatched by HTTPService. In particular, you did not add a "fault" event handler, and note that HTTPService doesn't dispatch the "security", "IOError", or "complete" events at all.